# Javascript TypeError variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am going through some very basic AJAX programming in "Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript -O'Reilly". There are a couple very basic programs with Java getting some text or a page with AJAX. I am using the W3Schools.com site to try to learn more about getting XML formatted docs with AJAX. I have two questions related to what I am learning.

When I used the code from http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp I can return an XML document with the snippet below:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

//called this way
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
```

But async has to be set to false for this to work. If I set async to true, it returns null. So my first question is why must async be false for this to return the XML document?

My second question, when I try to combine some of the code from the book and some from the website, snippet follows:

```
<body>API Call output
<div id='output'>will be here</div>
<script>
out = ""
xmlDoc = getResponse()
users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('username')
for (count = 0; count < users.length ; count++)
{
    out += "Username: " + users[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br />'
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out

function ajaxRequest()
{
    try //good browser
    {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    catch(e1)
    {
        try // IE6+
        {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch(e2)
        {
            request = false
        }
    }//end catch(e1)
    return request
}

function getResponse()
{
    params = "apikey=test"
    request = new ajaxRequest()
    request.open("POST", "processapi.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (this.status == 200)
            {
                if (this.responseXML != null)
                {
                    return this.responseXML
                }
                else alert("Ajax error: No data received")
            }
            else alert( "Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
        }
    }

    request.send(params)
}
</script>
</body>
```

I get an error that "TypeError: xmlDoc is undefined". In function getResponse() with async set to true or false it doesn't work, I get the xmlDoc is undefined error. The xmlDoc is not defined elsewhere in the first example (from w3schools.com) before being set to the return of loadXMLDoc() and that works just fine. the ajaxRequest() is out of the book, and most everything in getResponse() is out of the book, but I put it in the getResponse() function. processapi.php just echos an XML document when called from this script.

Why is async not working in the first example, and why is xmlDoc undefined in the second? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions lies in the nature of *asynchronousness*. With `async` being `true`, this returns `null`:

```
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
```

...because the HTTP request hasn't completed by the time the `return` statement occurs, and so `xhttp.responseXML` still has its default value (`null`). The HTTP request completes later, out of the flow of that code (asynchronously — literally, not synchronous).

Your `getResponse` function never returns a value at all. The anonymous callback function you've assigned to `onreadystatechange` returns a value, but that doesn't in any way affect the return value of `getResponse`.

One of the key aspects of client-side web programming is embracing the asynchronous, event-driven nature of the environment. There are virtually no use cases for setting `async` to `false` on XHR requests. Instead, get used to using callbacks for things. For instance, your `getResponse` function could look like this:

```
// ***CHANGE*** -----v--- Accept a callback
function getResponse(callback)
{
    params = "apikey=test"
    request = new ajaxRequest()
    request.open("POST", "processapi.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (this.status == 200)
            {
                if (this.responseXML != null)
                {
                    // ***CHANGE*** Trigger the callback with the response
                    callback(this.responseXML);
                }
                else alert("Ajax error: No data received")
            }
            else alert( "Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
        }
    }

    request.send(params)
}
```

Then, instead of this:

```
out = ""
xmlDoc = getResponse()
users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('username')
for (count = 0; count < users.length ; count++)
{
    out += "Username: " + users[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br />'
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out
```

you'd do this:

```
getResponse(function(xmlDoc) {
    out = ""
    users = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('username')
    for (count = 0; count < users.length ; count++)
    {
        out += "Username: " + users[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '<br />'
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out
});
```

Note how I moved all of the code that relied on the response into a function, and then passed that function into `getResponse`. `getResponse` calls it when it has the data. Request/response, event-driven, asynchronous, whatever you want to call it, this is a key thing to take onboard early. :-)

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Strongly recommend declaring all of your variables, and wrapping all of your code in a scoping function to avoid creating global symbols (the global namespace on browsers is already overcrowded).

Comment: Thank you. I used T.J's code and am going through it to understand what is going on. Looks like I will be reading about callbacks and implicit globals tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`getResponse` is doing asynchronous XHR requests so the function will return before the result is ready. You need to use a callback approach instead,

Change the function declaration to accept a callback parameter:

```
function getResponse(callback) {
```

Then modify this part in the function body

```
if (this.responseXML != null)
{
    return this.responseXML; // WRONG
}
```

so that it invokes the callback upon receiving the XML

```
if (this.responseXML != null)
{
    callback(this.responseXML); // GOOD
}
```

You would then call `getResponse` like this,

```
getResponse(function(xmlDoc){
   // do something with xmlDoc
})
```